# Importrange and concatenate

Tags: google-sheets

All,

I have been trying to import a range from a different sheet and concatenate two row/columns into one on import and I am failing at it horribly.

Here is the code I am using:

```
=IMPORTRANGE(("14ZDhy0VE-u0srsp1EZG6KaxMOusF8TzCcD2yWxPoxM0", "Aluminum!B1:H"),CONCATENATE(D:D,"","x","",E:E))
```

The image below shows the two columns and rows highlighted that need to be combined.

[Column Highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEIeZ.png)

Best,

D

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTRANGE(
 "14ZDhy0VE-u0srsp1EZG6KaxMOusF8TzCcD2yWxPoxM0", "Aluminum!D1:E")),, 9^9)), " ", " x "))
```